# Is "the disease yellow fever" a correct name?

Tags: grammar

[The source](http://www.yourerie.com/news/news-article/d/story/military-research-continues-fight-against-malaria/93129/JRd2vvSQOUiRtRkUTKmAQg):

> In Reed's case, it was **the disease yellow fever**, but this idea allowed William C. Gorgas to abate the transmission of yellow fever and malaria in the construction of the Panama Canal.

It seems like these words don't fit together. The structure is "the NOUN + ADJ + NOUN." To me it would sound better if it were: "the yellow fever disease," "yellow fever the disease."

Comment: *Yellow fever the disease* sounds like a title of some movie. It seems as if the 'yellow fever' is introduced as the disease. :)

Comment: *It's **we** who are responsible for that* is an example given in the book. Here, the word *disease* is renaming *yellow fever* and in such case, they generally follow the verb *to be* - Swan's Practical English

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

Here "yellow fever" is an **appositive** . It is noun-next-to-noun and behaves like an adjective (*describing disease*)

Sometimes the **appositive** is encapsulated in commas.

Comment: Should not be the adjective (or whatever purports to be the adjective) placed before the noun?

Comment: It follows the noun.....see....http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/appositive_apposition.htm

Comment: @Graduate It's exactly the same construction as  "Germany's Chancellor, Andrea Merkel" or "the composer Richard Strauss".

Comment: @StoneyB  Are there any rules concerning the need for commas.......when to use them......when to avoid them??